# How to create composite primary key in Spring, Jpa, Hibernate where one of the composite key is foreign key of another table with many to one join?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, many-to-one, composite-primary-key

I have two tables. For simplicity, here is [the schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIMjw.jpg).
As you can see, the table sensor_data has two composite key, where one of them is the foreign key of metadata id. There is a many to one relation between sensor_data and metadata, which means for each metadata, there can be many sensor_data but for each sensor_data, there can be only one metadata. I am still new to JPA and Hibernate, so I am strugling to implement it. Here is my code so far,

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@IdClass(SensorDataId.class)
public class SensorData {
    
    private Double x;
    private Double y;
    private Double z;

    @Id
    private Long timestamp;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="metadata_id", nullable=false)
    private Metadata metadata;
}



import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.io.Serializable;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class SensorDataId implements Serializable {
    private Long timestamp;
    private Metadata metadata;
}



import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Metadata{


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String dataObservationRound;
    private Long sensorNr;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "metadata")
    private List<SensorData> sensorDataList;

    public Metadata(String dataObservationRound, Long sensorNr) {
        this.dataObservationRound = dataObservationRound;
        this.sensorNr = sensorNr;
    }
}
```

However I am receiving the following exception.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.Long' to required type 'com.packagename.model.Metadata' for property 'metadata'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.Long' to required type 'com.packagename.model.Metadata' for property 'metadata': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

As my knowledge is quite limited, so I was only trying tie together separate tutorials on them, but I didn't find any that covers this specific scenario. Therefore any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the type of metadata variable to Long in SensorDataId and now it works.

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.io.Serializable;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class SensorDataId implements Serializable {
    private Long timestamp;
    private Long metadata;
}
```